# Putting Custom page summary in meta description

Tags: seo, google, html, google-search, meta-tags

if putting "Custom" `meta description` for EVERY page of site, is harmful for SEO?

(for example, summary of each article)

And Google will show them on SERPs?

Comment: Harmful? That's *exactly* what you should be doing!

Comment: Custom, human written meta descriptions and page titles everywhere helps. Do not use meta keywords though. If you choose to automate your meta descriptions to pull data from the page, make sure they are unique enough and add value. Ie: `Find your Fidget Widget at My Gidjet Company | 888-888-8888`

Answer (score 1):

Your meta description should describe what the page is about, not what the website is about .

If you have website about wood work, your meta data shouldn't be the same on all pages. If you had a page about a band saw, your meta description should reflect that it's about a band saw.

So no, it's not harmful, it will tell the users on the SERP exactly what the page is about.

Google will decide what it thinks best to show as the description but in most cases at least some portion of the description will be shown.

Comment: Google Webmaster Tools will even warn against duplicate titles / descriptions in the meta sections.

Answer (score 0):

Each page should have valuable content, a unique title, and a unique description. Your website should be mobile friendly. Having a legitimate meta description that is unique to that particular page cannot hurt SEO.